# Metamask (web3) connect wallet and send transaction - how to change blockchain to Bianance smart chain (BEP-20) network instead of Ethereum?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask, binance-smart-chain

[there](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/sending-transactions.html#example) is simple source code in HTML and JS about button to connecting wallet as a web3 and loading ETH transaction in Metamask.

**javascript**

```
const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
const sendEthButton = document.querySelector('.sendEthButton');

let accounts = [];

//Sending Ethereum to an address
sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ethereum
    .request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [
        {
          from: accounts[0],
          to: '0x2f318C334780961FB129D2a6c30D0763d9a5C970',
          value: '0x29a2241af62c0000',
          gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
          gas: '0x2710',
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
    .catch((error) => console.error);
});

ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getAccount();
});

async function getAccount() {
  accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="enableEthereumButton btn">Enable Ethereum</button>
<button class="sendEthButton btn">Send Eth</button>
```

I would like to ask, how to change code to determine loading of Binance smart chain network (BEP-20) instead of ETH.
I tried to find and change ETH contract which would be changed to BEP-20 contract but I don´t see contract there.

Second problem there is that this code contains value of 3 ETH which are loaded for transaction.

I would like to ask where is value set up to 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how to change code to determine loading of Binance smart chain network (BEP-20) instead of ETH*

You can send a [wallet_switchEthereumChain](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#usage-with-wallet-switchethereumchain) request to MetaMask. Code example in the linked documentation. BSC chain ID is 56 (decimal), which is 0x38 in hex, and the mainnet RPC URL is `https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/` ([source](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/connecting-metamask-to-binance-smart-chain)).

> *where is value set up to 3?*

It's the `value` param of the `eth_sendTransaction` method. `0x29a2241af62c0000` in hex is `3000000000000000000` in decimal, the amount of wei.

Comment: Yes, I had 56 there and it was problem. Thank´s